# Echoing User's Name on a homepage using a Session in Login.php

Tags: php, session, echo

Me and my friend are working on a website for his company. We want to have a welcome message displayed at the top of the page. I can get the username to display but not the name of that user so that after they log in and get to the main admin page it says Welcome, (name)! which is what I want.

Login.php

```
<?php

session_start();

$username = $_POST ['username'];
$password = $_POST ['password'];
if ($username&&$password)
{

$connect = mysql_connect ("localhost","(our login name)","") or die                
("Couldn't connect");
mysql_select_db ("jabluco1_surg3") or die ("DataBase does not exist");

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE username='$username'");

$numrows = mysql_num_rows ($query);

if ($numrows!=0)
{

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
$dbusername = $row['username'];
$dbpassword = $row['password'];
}

if ($username==$dbusername&&$password==$dbpassword&&$numrows>0)
{

$row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
header( 'Location: admin.php' ) ;
$_SESSION['name'] = $row['FirstName'];
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;

}
else    
echo "Incorrect Password!";

}
else 
die ("User Doesn't Exist");



}
else
die("Please try again!");




?>
```

echo on admin.php

```
<?php echo"Welcome, ".$_SESSION['name']."!"; ?>
```

It will echo the Hello,! and not the name.

Comment: Do you have `session_start()` at the top of admin.php?

Comment: You and your friend should research SQL injection attacks and use something other than the deprecated `mysql_*` functions.

Comment: yes both pages contain session_start() and alright I will look into it @ceejayoz.

Comment: would mysqli or pdo in this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your session will not be set as you have redirected to the `admin.php` already.

```
//header( 'Location: admin.php') ; // <--- Comment this
$_SESSION['name'] = $row['FirstName'];
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
header( 'Location: admin.php') ; //<-- Add here
exit;
```

**`EDIT :`**

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
    $dbusername = $row['username'];
    $dbpassword = $row['password'];
    $firstname = $row['FirstName'];
}

if ($username==$dbusername&&$password==$dbpassword&&$numrows>0)
{
    $_SESSION['name'] = $firstname;
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    header( 'Location: admin.php' );
    exit;
}
```

---

This(`mysql_*`) extension is deprecated as of `PHP 5.5.0`, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the `MySQLi` or `PDO_MySQL` extension should be used. Switching to `PreparedStatements` is even more better to ward off SQL Injection attacks !

Comment: Would I still need to use $row = mysql_fetch_array($query); after the if statement?

Comment: hmm..I did a switch around of the sessions and header and it still doesn't seem to echo the sesseion

Comment: AH! thank you very much this problem has been bugging me for weeks. Works great now. Problem solved

Answer (score 0):

also in admin.php

try something like this:

```
<?php 
 session_start();
 echo"Welcome, ".$_SESSION['name']."!"; 
?>
```

Comment: admin has a session_start(); at the top of the page already. Would adding another inside the php tags make a change?